# Wordpress meta_query LIKE compare values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a script that looks like this:

```
  foreach($target_zips as $zipcode) {

      $query_adresses = array (
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'cat'       => $_GET["cat"],
        'post_type'=> 'adressen',
        'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'postcode',
                'value'   => $zipcode,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
      );

      $results = get_posts( $query_adresses );

      $matched_adresses[] = $results;

  }
```

A script that goes through an array of values, then queries a lot of posts to see if there's posts that match meta_query. This is terribly slow. Is it possible to put an array of values in this meta_query instead of querying over and over again for each value in `$target_zips`?

Answer (score 2):

You can run just one get_posts() query that will return all the results. Build the meta_query beforehand.

```
$meta_query = [];


/**
 * This will return all posts that contain at least one meta_query from the loop
 */
$meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';


foreach ( $target_zips as $zipcode ) {
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key'     => 'postcode',
        'value'   => $zipcode,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];
}


$query_adresses   = [
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'cat'            => $_GET["cat"],
    'post_type'      => 'adressen',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query
];
$matched_adresses = get_posts( $query_adresses );
```

See this for for more details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. I finally got my head around my own query problem through your answer here!

Comment: ALWAYS sanitize ANY data coming from $_GET (or $_POST, $_REQUEST, etc)

Comment: This won't work. Searching for “123” using LIKE will also find “1234” and “0123”.

Answer (score 0):

C. Smiths solution is correct but there is a simpler solution.

You can utilize the IN clause in your compare key. Set the value key to an array of values that need to be compared.

More info and examples can be found here.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments

**Edit**

```
$query_adresses   = array (
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'cat'            => $_GET["cat"],
    'post_type'      => 'adressen',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'postcode',
            'value'   => $target_zips,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$matched_adresses = get_posts( $query_adresses );
```

**Note**

Like sMyles suggested, you MUST validate/sanitize your external data ($_GET)